# Duda refrescar array en Ionic 4

Tags: firebase, ionic, typescript

Buenas tengo problemas en refrescar un array en ionic de forma dinámica cada vez que salgo o entro de un componente.
En el constructor del componente tengo lo siguiente:

> ```
> constructor() {
>     this.refrescarLista();
> }
> ```

Y en el método "refrescarLista()" cargo el array con datos que recupero de firebase.

> ```
> refrescarLista() {
>      this.arrayCervezasBar = this.firebaseService.getListaFiltrada("bar- 
>       marca", "bar", this.nomUsuario);   
> }
> ```

En otro componente modifico el array a través de firebase, y al volver al componente del principio quiero que arrayCervezasBar se me actualice, porque no lo hace.

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: podrias usar emmit, puedo responder con emmit?